# How to move control at the correct position when Windows Forms is maximised

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using VB.NET and I have added buttons and text edits in a windows form.

When I press maximize button, the buttons and text edits do not cover the entire windows form.

[image: Problem]

I have checked the Docking method, but it works when I have few controls (like 2 or 3 buttons).

I will need to add around 20 button controls in the form.

How do I make sure the controls will move accordingly when the window form is maximized?

Thank you.

Comment: do you want them to move or resize?  The question seems to ask it both ways

Comment: Looks like you are in need of a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx).

Comment: @Plutonix, sorry I did not clarify my question. I want them to move, not resize.

Comment: If you want the controls to move when resizing then remove the anchoring of the controls. You can "lock" the Top property with only setting the Anchor property to Top, this way the controls will only move horizontally..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so obvious to automatically adapt the position of your child controls when the parent control resizes in Windows Forms, but do you really want that ?
It seems like a terrible idea for usability.
If you want to achieve this though, you should use a `TableLayoutPanel`, set the size of the columns/rows to a certain percentage and then fill the panel with your controls. Here is some sample code:

```
this.label1.AutoSize = true;
this.label1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 0);
this.label1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(7, 0, 7, 0);
this.label1.Name = "label1";
this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(84, 25);
this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
this.label1.Text = "label1";

this.label2.AutoSize = true;
this.label2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(105, 0);
this.label2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(7, 0, 7, 0);
this.label2.Name = "label2";
this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(84, 25);
this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
this.label2.Text = "label2";

this.tableLayoutPanel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label2, 1, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label1, 0, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(147, 107);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(196, 25);
this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 3;
```